# Where do I obtain Windows 7 64-bit drivers for the Apple Wireless Keyboard?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, 64-bit, wireless-keyboard

How can I install Apple Wireless Keyboard on Windows 7 x64 running on a non-Apple hardware?

The operating system does see the keyboard but it doesn't want to pair with it at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For pairing I had to reset keyboard memory by powering it down and powering it on by keeping the power button for more than 3 seconds.

For drivers, required for Fn key ussage, check 
[Does Apple Magic Mouse fully work on Windows 7 x86/x64?](https://superuser.com/questions/88912/does-apple-magic-mouse-fully-work-on-windows-7-x86-x64)

Answer (score 1):

After 3 frustrating hours of trying every tip on the net, I found [the answer](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_update/window%20s-update-yi-ruan-bluetooth-hid-device-driver/5bfd0c92-1771-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf%205?page=2&tm=1304484508563): Try this:

> This finally fixed it for me: Device
>   Manager - Open System Devices, you
>   will find a Bluetooth HID Device.
>   Double Click it, open Driver tab and
>   click "Update Driver" Select Browse my
>   Computer, then "Let me Pick". It
>   should now show TWO compatible drivers
>   with exactly the same name. One of
>   them is the Microsoft one, one is the
>   non-working Chinese ****. Install one
>   of them and see if the driver
>   properties changed to the right
>   (Microsoft) driver. If not, try again
>   with the other one. For me, the
>   Microsoft driver was the first one in
>   the list, but this may be different
>   for you. Wow, an annoying and intense
>   hour of trouble shooting finally
>   over...

The issue is related to the Chinese version of the driver that the latest Windows Update applies, and stops the keyboard from working.

I'm finally able to type this using an Apple Wireless Keyboard on my Windows 7 64-bit PC!

Answer (score 0):

I have been using the [open source WinA1314 driver](https://github.com/samartzidis/WinA1314) with great success! There are download links on the bottom of the project's page for both 64 bit or 32 bit Windows.

Comment: Are you running Windows on a Mac laptop ? I tried this WinA1314, weirdly it only works for 2-3 minutes, then the keyboard just disappear. Is there any similar problem with you ?

Comment: I'm using a Windows 7 (64 bit) laptop (Dell Latitude E6530). You might want to make sure your batteries are fresh, just in case.

Comment: pretty sure it's not my battery :) ! I swap in 2 new batteries just last week. The thing is: Apple Wireless Keyboard appears in Device Manager for 1-2 minutes and it disappeared. FYI this keyboard is working fine with my Mac