# Does Apple Magic Mouse fully work on Windows 7 x86/x64?

Tags: windows-7, mouse, 64-bit, magic-mouse

I would like to know if Apple Magic Mouse works on Windows 7 (x86/x64) on non-Apple computers.

Here are some checklists:

- x64 compatibility
- left click
- right click
- middle button?
- vertical scroll
- horizontal scroll
- bind additional gestures to keystrokes?
- are any usage problems?

In case it works please advise on how to get the drivers.

Comment: Currently I found one big problem using the Magic Mouse, it has a resolution of only 1300dpi this is far less than my Microsoft Wireless Notebook Optical Mouse making the Apple mouse a not desired experience. Also you cannot tweak the mouse speedup for each of them - the Control Panel option change the speed for both.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can download the latest installers (from **Boot Camp 3.1**):

- [AppleMouse-31.exe](http://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B3hEMkuRLxRhNWU3NjIwNWEtMDBjNi00M2JjLThjYjAtZmIwY2YyNjk5MGM5&hl=en)
- [AppleKeyboard-31.exe](http://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B3hEMkuRLxRhZmQyNjhlNzYtNjdhYi00MjdlLWI4OTItMzM5YWVjNzhhZDdi&hl=en)

They are working with both Wireless products including the new Magic Mouse. I'm not sure if these are including only x64 versions.

Comment: If you want to get the files directly from apple see instructions here http://superuser.com/questions/634398/windows-8-gestures-with-apple-magic-mouse/823906#823906

Answer (score 3):

As of today I have the mouse working with Windows 7 Ultimate x64 on a Dell D630 using the Dell bluetooth.

Apple drivers from bootcamp 3.1, downloaded today, unpacked with 7-zip.

The only things on your list that are not working are middle-click and gestures, but I haven't had it long nor used it extensively so it's early to call it "great" but already a huge improvement over the trackpad.

Answer (score 2):

http://uneasysilence.com/archive/2009/11/14588/ - apparently 32-bit *and* 64-bit drivers for Windows XP to Windows 7. Haven't personally tried it though.

Answer (score 2):

Yes the Magic Mouse works with Windows 7. If you are using Boot Camp 2.x from Leopard, you can acquire the driver from the [Boot Camp 2.2 updat](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL967)e. If you are using Boot Camp 3.0 from Snow Leopard, [you can extract the driver from the Boot Camp 2.2 .exe file using 7-zip](http://thoughtfulcode.wordpress.com/2009/12/16/make-your-own-apple-boot-camp-3-1-update/).

Comment: what if you are not using boot camp?