# How can I use the Apple Bluetooth Keyboard on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, drivers, wireless-keyboard

I just bought the Apple Aluminium Bluetooth Keyboard, and obviously it doesn't work on my Windows machine.

I'm guessing the drivers aren't installed. It says it has successfully paired with the device, but nothing seems to work.

Has anyone successfully paired the keyboard with a Windows machine?

Comment: Based on the numerous questions about this keyboard it DOES work on Windows. Clearly any non-Windows keys will not work within Windows unless you map them.  Try reading and download the files described here: http://superuser.com/questions/88912/does-apple-magic-mouse-fully-work-on-windows-7-x86-x64

Comment: Ramhound - The link you provided is related to the magic mouse, cvista is asking about the bluetooth keyboard

Comment: nope - had both mouse and keyboard - working great

Answer (score 0):

Driver should be pretty much automatic. Check out the [Apple Wireless Keyboard Helper Utility](http://www.redmondpie.com/use-apple-wireless-keyboard-on-windows-with-full-functionality-using-apple-wireless-keyboard-helper/) ([download location](http://www.redmondpie.com/use-apple-wireless-keyboard-on-windows-with-full-functionality-using-apple-wireless-keyboard-helper/)) for full fucnitonality (volume control, task managner, eject, etc). I use my apple wireless keyboard with my Win7 machine all day, every day.