# Windows 8 gestures with apple magic mouse

Tags: windows-8, magic-mouse

I want to be able to use Windows 8 Gestures with apple magic mouse, is it possible?

I tried to find some clue but unable to get any...

Can we use touch surface on mouse as touch pad maybe?

Answer (score 2):

I have an apple magec mouse running on my Surface Pro 3 with Windows 8.1. It supports vertical and horizontal scrolling. I haven't tried other gestures.

You can install the drivers for apple magic mouse like this:

1. [Download 7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html)
2. Download Bootcamp software from here: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1336
3. Use 7zip to unzip the download exe (right-click > 7zip > extract here)
4. Use 7zip to unzip the `BootCampUpdate64.msp` file
5. Open the `BootCamp31ToBootCamp303` folder from the extracted files
6. Rename `Binary.MultiTouchMouse_Bin` to `Binary.MultiTouchMouse_Bin.exe`
7. Run that file and follow the wizard to install the drivers
8. If you previously had the mouse installed, go to Bluetooth devices and Remove it, then re-pair

Comment: Thanks for nice answer, I just wanted to use mouse as touch pad.